# Git Branches In Xamarin Studio

Tags: git, github, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I currently have 3 branches in a remote git repo and want to switch to one of them in XS. However XS is only showing the master branch.

Similarly doing a 'git branch -a' in terminal only returns one remote branch:

```
git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/master
```

However doing a git ls-remote returns all the branches

```
git ls-remote

a72db09adb82fdf2452d2ecb9ca2d4a48ad86d89    HEAD
628160ed4c92d0c6ea46db77cb94d89e3748dcad    refs/heads/Database
a72db09adb82fdf2452d2ecb9ca2d4a48ad86d89    refs/heads/Interface
a72db09adb82fdf2452d2ecb9ca2d4a48ad86d89    refs/heads/master
```

If someone could assist me in pulling down another branch (Interface) that would be great!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hit fetch? That's what I do on the command line or in PHPStorm / IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

`git branch -r` will also allow you to see all remote branches.

`git checkout origin/Interface` should switch to the Interface branch (is that an option through that `Checkout...` menu item?)

Comment: git branch -r only shows origin/master - checkout will checkout the branch as a whole new project, will checkout the master then would have to switch. Although can't switch as it only shows the one branch! Thanks